# How can i make a text button in HTML

Tags: html, css, button, photography

I am making a photography website and I wanted to have a gallery of images and a list like

- Wildlife
- Landscape
- Ocean

and when I click on them it opens a gallery of images.

I tried looking some tutorials up on youtube and google but couldn't find anything and since I'm not very experienced in HTML and CSS I don't know where to start

Currently I only have a gallery like this

```html
<h1>###&nbsp;</h1>


<h1>###</h1>

<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="Images/plant_with_web.png" height="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="Images/rock_in_water.png" height="150" width="200" alt="rock_on_log" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="Images/rock_on_log.png" height="150" width="200" alt="sunset" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="Images/Rocks.png" height="150" width="200" alt="sun_on_beach" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="Images/sunset.png" height="150" width="200" alt="rock_in_water" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="Images/waves_crashing.png" height="150" width="200" alt="bird" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="Images/bird.png" height="150" width="200" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="Images/birdrock.png" height="150" width="200" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="Images/DSC04758.jpg" height="150" width="200" />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend the use of a table for a gallery. You can maybe put each gallery in a different html page and use the  tag to access them. like:

```
<a href="wildlife.html">Wildelife</a>
```

But if you want them to appear or slide dynamically on the same page you may need some javascript or jquery.

Comment: i had considered the idea but specifically did not want to use it

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this??

```css
button {
    background-color:white;
    border:0px;
}

button:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    }
```

```html
<button> Button 1 as a text
</button>

<button> Button 2 as a text
</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button#wildlife").click(function() {
    $(".wildlife> img").toggle();
    $(".landscape> img").hide();
    $(".ocean> img").hide();
  });

  $("button#landscape").click(function() {
    $(".landscape> img").toggle();
    $(".ocean> img").hide();
    $(".wildlife> img").hide();
  });

  $("button#ocean").click(function() {
    $(".ocean> img").toggle();
    $(".wildlife> img").hide();
    $(".landscape> img").hide();
  });

});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 0px;
}

button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.landscape>img {
  display: none;
}

.ocean>img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <button id="wildlife">Wildlife</button><br>
  <button id="landscape">Landscape</button><br>
  <button id="ocean">Ocean</button>

  <div class="wildlife">
    <img src=https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/squirrel-silhouette-hand-drawn-image-260nw-748191586.jpg eight="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src=https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/squirrel-silhouette-hand-drawn-image-260nw-748191586.jpg eight="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src=https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/squirrel-silhouette-hand-drawn-image-260nw-748191586.jpg eight="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src=https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/squirrel-silhouette-hand-drawn-image-260nw-748191586.jpg eight="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src=https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/squirrel-silhouette-hand-drawn-image-260nw-748191586.jpg eight="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src=https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/squirrel-silhouette-hand-drawn-image-260nw-748191586.jpg eight="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
  </div>

  <div class="landscape">
    <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/54/cb/51/beautiful-morning-green.jpg" height="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/54/cb/51/beautiful-morning-green.jpg" height="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/54/cb/51/beautiful-morning-green.jpg" height="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/54/cb/51/beautiful-morning-green.jpg" height="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/54/cb/51/beautiful-morning-green.jpg" height="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/54/cb/51/beautiful-morning-green.jpg" height="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
  </div>


  <div class="ocean">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/school-dolphins-underwater-photography-260nw-1582116775.jpg" height="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/school-dolphins-underwater-photography-260nw-1582116775.jpg" height="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/school-dolphins-underwater-photography-260nw-1582116775.jpg" height="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/school-dolphins-underwater-photography-260nw-1582116775.jpg" height="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/school-dolphins-underwater-photography-260nw-1582116775.jpg" height="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/school-dolphins-underwater-photography-260nw-1582116775.jpg" height="150" width="200" alt="rocks" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem.

However, if you are trying to make a button then use the `<input type='text'> button </input>` or the button element.

Or if you want an image to be clickable then use `<a href="image_URL"><img href="image_URL></a>"`

Comment: i had also asked a question about clickable images you just answered that one thanks, i guess :D

Answer (score 0):

If galleries are on their separate page: use `<a href="SITE.COM/gallary/wildlife">Wildlife</a>`

If galleries will open as a full screen pop-up: use `<button id="wildlife">Wildlife</button>`

You can also use `<details><summary>` element to get the same functionality without depending more on JavaScript

---

**EDIT 1:**

**you can us a js library like [PhotoSwipe](https://photoswipe.com/),
it could fit perfectly in your use case**

Comment: alright ill try it

Comment: this isnt exactly what i was looking for but will work perfectly for another project of mine thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use input type="submit" value="add"

Value mean Name
This button name is add

Answer (score 0):

you should use `<a href="/"><img src="" alt="" /></a>`

Comment: i didnt want to use seperate pages

Answer (score 0):

Hey your question is a bit unclear, but if you want a button that you click that opens up a wildlife gallery you can have something like this `<button> <a href = www.wildlife-photos.com/gallery></a> Wildlife </button>` or just make a page called wildlife.html and make the button direct to it `<button> <a href = wildlife.html></a> Wildlife </button>`

I hope this helps :D
Sorry if this isn't much of a direction.

Comment: i didnt want to make more pages because my website is supposed to be minimilistic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).